# Run custom code on Android/iOS using Appium

Tags: android, appium

I'm using appium framework for UI end to end tests. I want to make https API call on the device and verify the result after the UI toggle is turned on/off. I don't want to use adb shell curl/nc to accomplish this task. Is there a way to execute custom script on android device?

I searched the Appium API doc for a way to accomplish this. I couldn't find a way.

Comment: It is not clear from your description what exactly you are trying to do